# Difference between myFun() and function myFun

Tags: bash, function

As a new(ish) user to bash, what is the difference between `myFun()` and `funtion myFun`? I have run into both, not just in people's code but in tutorials as well. Is there any difference between the two? When I tried it out, nothing different seems to happen, so I am fairly sure that these two methods to define a function are just different syntactically and are not run differently at all, but could someone confirm this assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a big difference between these two syntaxes for defining functions:

```
   name() compound-command
   function name compound-command
```

[The former is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05) and, therefore, widely portable.  The latter is not.  Otherwise, they are identical.

#### Examples

`dash` is the default shell (`/bin/sh`) on debian-like systems.  Observe that, under `dash`, this method of defining a function is successful:

```
$ fn() { date; }
$ fn
Mon Nov 24 14:27:49 PST 2014
```

But, this method is not:

```
$ function fn { date; }  
dash: 2: function: not found
```

There is a similar error under `ash` (busybox's shell):

```
$ function fn { date; }
-sh: function: not found
```